# High level mp3 player library under linux

Tags: linux, embedded, mp3

I need to add some mp3 file playing functionality to my Linux based embedded application. Until now I used a system call (`mpg123 -qm list of mp3 files`). But now I don't have all the elements of the playlist, but get the next one only when I'm ready with the previous one.  With mpg123 it means that I have some stupid noise between the tracks, as I always have to restart the mpg123 binary.

I was looking around for some libraries and found libmad, lame, sdl and co. But they seem to be a bit overcomplicated at first to handle. I found the fmod (http://www.fmod.org/index.php/download) library easy to use. But it's available only in binary format, which doesn't fit my ARM-based target (not to mention the licensing problems). Does anybody know about any similar, open source library capable of playing mp3 files similar to fmod?

Comment: Did you try VLC Player libraries ?

Comment: i fear it would be to heavy for me in this context...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally with the help of houbysoft's hint i found a solution which uses libmpg123 and libao, [here](http://hzqtc.github.com/2012/05/play-mp3-with-libmpg123-and-libao.html), and with some tuning i managed to get pretty smooth file-by-file playing. Thx for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

`mpg123` has an [API](http://www.mpg123.de/api/), perhaps you could use that instead of calling the binary?

Comment: hm, yes i didn't notice this one before, but as i see, it doesn't support soundplaying, only en/decoding, so now i'm playing around a solution based on this: http://hzqtc.github.com/2012/05/play-mp3-with-libmpg123-and-libao.html

Comment: @user1494352: you might want to post that as an answer and self-accept.